# Why doesn't this code display any output?

Tags: python

I wrote a function that printed out the min & max of the numbers in the list, but when I switched print with return the code doesn't seem to print a thing, so I ran the same code with the return statement in the python console and it work, I want to know why the code works with the python console in terminal and why it doesn't when I run the script as python3 Code.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.5
#
#
def Ehlo():
    nums = [1,5,2,4,6,12,8,9,3]

    return (min(nums))
    #return (max(nums))

Ehlo()
```

Comment: You should read more about how return works. This should be a good start: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7129285/why-would-you-use-the-return-statement-in-python

Comment: What did you expect the code to do by having two return statements ? maybe what you actually wanted is something like: `return min(nums), max(nums)`

Comment: Also see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21278736/why-doesnt-python-print-return-values), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3881434/difference-between-returns-and-printing-in-python), and a ton of other results that you can find by Googling the difference between printing and returning.

Comment: For the same reason that putting `1 + 1` in a file by itself and running it doesn't display `2`.

Answer (score 2):

1. You cannot use 2 returns. The first return will return the minimum value and the second return will never be reached.
2. The value returned is not being printed.

Try this -

```
def Ehlo():
   nums = [1,5,2,4,6,12,8,9,3]
   return (min(nums)),(max(nums))

print(Ehlo())
```

Output: (1,12)

Answer (score 0):

This is how Python behaves: In a script you will always need a print statement to see a visible result. However, in the console entering the name of a variable (or returning something as in your case from a routine) will automatically print the value.